# Android: 7218 30969 F libc : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x72745324 in tid 30969 (media), pid 7218

Tags: android, memory, segmentation-fault, heap-memory

I have an Android application with a huge C/C++ code base. Once in a while the application is crashing with:

```
05-17 20:16:10.407  7218 30969 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x72745324 in tid 30969 (media), pid 7218

05-17 20:16:10.568  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-17 20:16:10.569  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: samsung/starltexx/starlte:10/QP1A.190711.020/G960FXXUHFVG4:user/release-keys
05-17 20:16:10.569  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : Revision: '26'
05-17 20:16:10.569  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
05-17 20:16:10.569  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2023-05-17 20:16:10+0200
05-17 20:16:10.569  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : pid: 7218, tid: 30969, name: media
05-17 20:16:10.569  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : uid: 10419
05-17 20:16:10.570  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x72745324
05-17 20:16:10.570  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :     r0  bfc3002c  r1  72745320  r2  00000000  r3  d7a13e0f
05-17 20:16:10.570  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :     r4  000000de  r5  b4ebeb28  r6  0000003c  r7  c0caf850
05-17 20:16:10.570  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :     r8  b5305e70  r9  c1d87018  r10 c0cafa60  r11 ee0c7260
05-17 20:16:10.570  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :     ip  bdc5b0b0  sp  c0caf6d8  lr  baa02675  pc  bb26745a
05-17 20:16:10.616  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : 
05-17 20:16:10.616  4069  4069 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-17 20:16:10.617  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0345045a   (QueueBuffer::duration() const+550) 
05-17 20:16:10.617  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 03450029  (getRecvBuffer(unsigned int, void*, unsigned int, unsigned int*, pjmedia_frame*)+108) 
05-17 20:16:10.617  4069  4069 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0344d3e9
```

Looking at the back trace does not provide any obvious clues as why it is crashing. I was wondering if there is a way to determine where this address 0xeed8fce0 is referring to. Clearly the address is no longer mapped in the address space of the application or at least the application is denied access to this address.

Best regards, Rene

Comment: I am not sure if the address will be of much help as the crash reason is that this address points to a wrong location. What you need would be a stack trace of the crashing thread to find it's origin.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean by "stack trace of the crashing thread". There is back trace which I added now in the description. This is basically a call stack. It is still useful - though the address is obviously invalid - to know to which object 0x72745324 is pointing ... duration() iterates over a buffer containing frames. When there is a crash (but this is sporadically) the last frame in the buffer can not be processed, but I cannot manage to print the address of the last frame when the app crashes ... unclear why suddenly the last frame in the buffer would be on an invalid address ...

Comment: Is "media" the name of tid "30969"?

Comment: Yes, seems like "media" is the name of the thread where the invalid access occurs.

Comment: QueueBuffer::duration() const+550 -> what is meaning of "+550"?

Comment: That should be the address offset to the current function where the error occurred. Not sure if this number is decimal or hexadecimal. If you would open the binary in a decompiler like Ghidra or IDA pro you could loo at the address offset of the method `QueueBuffer::duration()` and then add 550 to get to the point to get the assembler command that failed.