# Android SDK emulator: crasher strlen-NULL

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, null-pointer

https://source.android.com/docs/core/tests/debug/native-crash says:
"You can reproduce an instance of this type of crash using crasher strlen-NULL."

How to do that actually? Open a "adb shell" to the Android emulator. next? crasher is part of debuggerd, but the only help debuggerd shows is:

```
127|x1s:/ $ debuggerd --help
usage: debuggerd [-bj] PID

-b, --backtrace    just a backtrace rather than a full tombstone
-j                 collect java traces
1|x1s:/ $ crasher --help 
/system/bin/sh: crasher: inaccessible or not found
```

BR, Rene

Comment: I would assume that `crasher`  is binary available in the Android emulator images (never seen it on real devices). Source code of crasher: https://chromium.googlesource.com/aosp/platform/system/core/+/refs/heads/upstream/debuggerd/crasher/ BTW: A "null pointer dereference" may have the same error text but is is a different error compared to what you had described in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76303959/150978

Comment: Freshly installed Android Studio + SDK. Got emulator working from command line. Can connect to emulator using "adb shell". Can still not execute "crasher". Edited the question a bit to indicate more precisely what I tried to do in the emulator. But results are the same for me on a device or on the emulator.

Comment: Maybe you have to compile the emulator yourself with STATIC_CRASHER enabled?